# Java/Yahoo Finance Retrieving Quotes, Error 401

Tags: java, yahoo-finance

Here's my Java code to download historical Yahoo finance quotes using crumbs. Sorry, it's not the most efficient code. I'm still learning Java. Everything looks correct to me, but I get error 401 after picking up the crumb and trying to make the second access to "https"//query1.finance.yahoo.com..."

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
    URL myUrl = null;
    try {
        myUrl = new URL("https://finance.yahoo.com");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection urlConn = null;
    try {
        urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        urlConn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String headerName=null;
    String crumb = null;
    for (int i = 1; (headerName = urlConn.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
        if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {                  
            String cookie = urlConn.getHeaderField(i);

             cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
             crumb = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.indexOf("&"));
            }
    }

    StringBuilder qUrl = new StringBuilder();
    qUrl.append("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL");
    qUrl.append("?period1=" + 1495813803L);
    qUrl.append("&period2=" + 1497887408L);
    qUrl.append("&interval=1d");
    qUrl.append("&events=history");
    qUrl.append("&crumb=" + crumb);

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(qUrl.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection conn;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        conn = url.openConnection();
        String redirect = conn.getHeaderField("Location");              // Can handle one redirection
        if(redirect != null ) {
            conn = new URL(redirect).openConnection();
        }
        is = conn.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: A 401 response usually indicates that you are not authorized.  Read the Yahoo API documentation carefully paying special attention to the bit about authorization and authentication.  It may also be that you are simply hitting the wrong URL.  In either case, the soln. is to read the docs carefully.

Comment: This is an undocumented API and so there's no info on-line.  I'm basically following the suggestion from Joshua Rich: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/commit/793601805c5d7291d5cda22ce4df4001a40ff312, but my struggle is converting this to working Java code.

Comment: Yahoo's web services are very well-documented.  Start here: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

Comment: Thanks, but somehow digging into YQL doesn't seem like it's going to help solve my issue. I need help picking up crumbs that Yahoo uses to thwart folks like me from easily skimming data. What's really ironic is that on the YQL site, Yahoo themselves boast how their tools can be used to "Easily Scape HTML"!

Comment: Hey Alano, did you find a solution? I am experiencing the same thing, and is trying to find a way to obtain the crumb.

Comment: Yes use this library https://github.com/sstrickx/yahoofinance-api